# Make second user also a device owner

Tags: adb, multi-user, accounts

I recently bought Samsung Galaxy tab s5e , and configured my account for it. Afterwards I created account (using android multiuser feature ) for my wife.
Hovewer the second account is very limited due to android security features . It lacks some serttings, Samsung DeX, and access to SD card. I do know the security reasoning for it ,and I don't care about them.

Is there some ADB command, tweak or some other way( for example after rooting device) to make the second account also a device owner (administrator ), grant access to sd cards and stuff , otherwise the security feature is kind of usseles if you realy want to have multi user experience on tablet

Comment: Same issue with Tab S6 Lite and secondary users I created for my kids - no SD card access.